# How to read and write a list of users in a text file

Tags: c#

Hello I'm trying to learn C# and although I have looked I haven't found a way of solving my problem.

I have a Users class with a Username, Password, Score.
And all of them have setters and getters.

What I'm trying to do is:

After I create my List : ListOfUsers I wanna save all of the users of that list in a single text file (Login.txt)

I tried this:

```
Users user = new Users(username, password, score);
ListOfUsers.Add(user);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Login.txt", true);
sw.WriteLine(ListOfUsers);
sw.Close();
```

I think that I have passed the list into my file. But I can't seem to find a way of reading all the users from the file.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Is it just a student task or a real application? If not a student task, you should never do anything like that (storing in the file, storing passwords in plain text) with passwords and user data.

Comment: It's something that I wanna try cause I had that idea. It is not for a real application.
I know it is not the best way(safest) of storing data. I'm just learning.

Comment: I don't think that you are writing the list to the file correctly. You probably should choose some particular format, serialize data into it, and only then be writing to the file. For example, you can use JSON for data serialization.

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\Login.txt", ListOfUsers.Select(user => $"{user.UserName}"));` or alike

Comment: @VladimirSerykh Thank you for your answers and suggestions but before I move on to something more advanced like that I just wanted to try it. But I can't seem to figure out how to read the data from the file properly.

Comment: `File.WriteAllText("File",JsonConvert.Serialize(ListOfUsers));`, `var user JsonConvert.Deserialize(File.ReadAllText("File"));` Download Json.net nuget

Comment: Your class for each user is called `Users` (as in plural). That is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save to a text file, at least make it an `Xml` file, instead of a flat file. The code below adds users to a list, saves it as an Xml, clears the list, and then reads from the file.

The Xml file looks like this:

```
<ArrayOfUser xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <User Name="A" Password="AAA" Score="100" />
  <User Name="B" Password="BBB" Score="87" />
  <User Name="C" Password="CCC" Score="52" />
</ArrayOfUser>
```

And the sample source code

```
public class User 
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Name= string.Empty;
        this.Password = string.Empty;
        this.Score= 0;
    }
    public User(string name, string password, int score)
    {
        Name=name;
        Password=password;
        Score=score;
    }
    [XmlAttribute] public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute] public string Password { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute] public int Score { get; set; }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<User>();
        list.Add(new User("A", "AAA", 100));
        list.Add(new User("B", "BBB", 87));
        list.Add(new User("C", "CCC", 52));

        SaveToXml(list.ToArray(), "Login.xml");

        list.Clear();
        list.AddRange(ReadFromXml("Login.xml"));

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name}, {item.Score}");
        }
    }

    static void SaveToXml(User[] users, string fileName)
    {
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User[]));
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings()
        {
            Indent = true,
            OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
        };
        var xw = XmlWriter.Create(fileName, settings);
        xs.Serialize(xw, users);
        xw.Close();
    }

    static User[] ReadFromXml(string fileName)
    {
        var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(User[]));
        var xr = XmlReader.Create(fileName);
        return xs.Deserialize(xr) as User[];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Vladimir told, better don't save any login data to a text file (even better don't save it at all).

In any way, if it's something you have to do for any reason, you can look here: [here](https://www.guru99.com/c-sharp-serialization.html)

After that, I suggest you to encrypt the file, so nobody can read the content except the user that creates the file itself: [How to crypt/decrypt file](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.io.file.encrypt?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Better to avoid answer with a link but without exact info. It will be flagged and removed. Just put the information and code samples here.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like that, some time ago. Here's the example.

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialog.Filter = "Archivo de texto (*.txt)|*.txt";
saveFileDialog.FileName = $"Compras_Auxiliar_{(int)Periodo.Value}{_ejercicioContableManager.SearchById(_idEjercicioContable).Anio}_{_empresaManager.SearchById(_idEmpresa).Nit}.txt";
saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   List<BancarizacionCompra> listaBancarizacionCompra = _bancarizacionComprasManager.ObtenerTodo.Where(bancarizacion => bancarizacion.EsProyecto == false).ToList();

    string[] lines = new string[listaBancarizacionCompra.Count()];
    for (int i = 0; i < listaBancarizacionCompra.Count(); i++)
    {
        lines[i] = $"{(int)listaBancarizacionCompra[i].ModalidadTransaccion}|{listaBancarizacionCompra[i].FechaDocumentoPago.ToShortDateString()}|{(int)listaBancarizacionCompra[i].TipoTransaccion}|{listaBancarizacionCompra[i].CiNitProveedor}|{listaBancarizacionCompra[i].NombreRazonSocialProveedor}|{listaBancarizacionCompra[i].NombreRazonSocialProveedor}|{listaBancarizacionCompra[i].NumeroFactura}|{listaBancarizacionCompra[i].NumeroContrato}|{listaBancarizacionCompra[i].ImporteFacturaDocumento.ToString("c").Replace(".", "").Replace(",", ".")}|{listaBancarizacionCompra[i].NumAutorizacionFacturaDocumento}|{listaBancarizacionCompra[i].NumCuentaDocumentoPago}|{listaBancarizacionCompra[i].MontoPagadoDocumentoPago.ToString("c").Replace(".", "").Replace(",", ".")}|{listaBancarizacionCompra[i].MontoAcumulado.ToString("c").Replace(".", "").Replace(",", ".")}|{listaBancarizacionCompra[i].NitEntidadFinanciera}|{listaBancarizacionCompra[i].NumDocumentoPago}|{(int)listaBancarizacionCompra[i].TipoDocumentoPago}|{listaBancarizacionCompra[i].FechaDocumentoPago.ToShortDateString()}";
    }
    File.WriteAllLines(saveFileDialog.FileName, lines);

    Mensajes.CrearMensajeInformativo("Exportación exitosa");
    if (Mensajes.CrearMensajeInterrogacion("¿Desea abrir el archivo?"))
    {
        Process.Start(saveFileDialog.FileName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the expectation that you are using dotnet 3.1 or higher you can use:

#### Option 1

Using just the `File` class.

```
// System.Text.Json serializer
await File.WriteAllTextAsync("Login.txt", JsonSerializer.Serialize(ListOfUsers));
```

#### Option 2

The other option without `File` is to use a `StreamWriter` instead.

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter("Login.txt", true))
{
    // System.Text.Json serializer
    await sw.WriteLineAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(ListOfUsers));
}
```

Both will at the end produce the "Login.txt" file with a JSON format of the users list.

In case you are using a lower version than dotnet 3.1 you need to include [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which provides another JSON serializer:

```
// Newtonsoft serializer
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListOfUsers);
```

**Important:** Be aware (like written in the comments and other answers) this data is not encrypted and should not be written in that way.